# AppCompat toolbar dark theme style not working on pre 21 devices

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

First of all I have repeatedly read and applied everything posted here, but it does not solve my problem. It seems that every answer posted here is to apply style to theme attribute of the toolbar, i've tried it it got me nowhere, so let me explain what my problem is:

I want to have light theme everywhere except the toolbar. On Lollipop devices, it's not a problem, but on pre Lollipop devices toolbars Title and overflow button always adopts MyTheme parent style, so I get dark Title and dark overflow button (it's my only button there) it seems like theme attribute is malfunctioning in Toolbar.

I'm using AppCompatActivity for my base class, my minimum api is 15 and AppCompat version is 22.2.1.0

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item> 
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary_color</item> 
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

[image: Toolbar with dark title]

my hamburger item is white because I inflate image from resource

```
var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
SupportActionBar.Title = "Sport";

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

 if (SupportActionBar != null){
 SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `android:theme`?

Comment: Well try `app:theme` for both pre-lollipop and lollipop devices it should work just fine

Comment: "app" is just custom name for  "..res-auto" i call it "local" (Mvx standard). So instead "app:theme" I have "local:theme". It's same thing.

Comment: android:theme does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    local:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ToolbarTheme"  parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar when parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the text of the action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the overflow menu icon -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item> 
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary_color</item> 
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
</style>
```

In this case ColorControlNormal colored overflow icon and titleTextColor colored Title. It seems that in my case ToolbarTheme doesn't work. I don't have a clue why is it, but now I don't care. This is not an optimal solution but it works.

Comment: You can use `android:theme` instead of `local:theme`. Recent versions of appcompat use android:theme for the local view theming instead of app:theme. However, you still use app:popupTheme (local:popupTheme in your case) for the popup menu theme.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it worked, I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Try This combination in your toolbar code it should work just fine.

Comment: It does not work for me. Title and overflow button are still from light scheme.

Comment: can you send a screenshot?